# How to implement contact plugin in netbeans?

Tags: cordova, netbeans-8

I am running cordova Application in netbeans. How to implement the contact plugin? Installation of the plugin has been done.
 Any help would appreciated.

Comment: As you have added the plugin, you can follow examples given in  cordova documentation [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/index.html)

Comment: you can use the methods given there as per your requirement